# command copy in command promt

Tags: copy, cmd

ok I know this a really generic question but I nedd to copy a folder from command promt (I'm creating a .bat archive) but I can't make it work can somebody help me at least with the syntax. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you've tried? Have you used `COPY /?` to get help on the command line?

Comment: try cp -rf to force and recursive

Comment: I tryed copy source C:\Users\ElMonk\Pictures\Locust_Drone_3D_Poster_en-US destiny C:\Program Files (x86) and it told it coudn't find the specified file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .bat file first make the folder you want to copy to (if it doesn't exist)

```
mkdir destinationFolder
```

then copy files

```
copy soureFolder destinationFolder
```

Comment: just separated with a blank space the name of both dirs?

Comment: Yes. Also, if you have blanks in your folder names, use quotes around the names to escape them.